# Let $L \supset K$ be an extension field. Prove $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n) = K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})(a_n)$ ? Why smallest subfield with properties?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $L \supset K$ is an extension field. How do one prove rigorously that $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n) = K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})(a_n)$ ?

I understand that $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ is the smallest subfield of $L$ containing $K$ and $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$. Is it enough to say that $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1})(a_n)$ is also a smallest field of $L$ containing the above set and elements and therefore they are equal ?

How do I see that $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ is indeed the smallest subfield containing containing $K$ and $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ ? (It is defined as the fractions of $K[a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n]$). Here "smallest" mean that $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ is a subfield of any other field containing $K$ and $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ ?

The smallest subfield of $L$ containing $K$ and $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ must exist, since we can take the intersection of subfields of $L$ with the given properties and we know at least one such subfield of $L$ exist namely $L$ ? But why is this subfield equal to $K(a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ ?

Comment: I guess that's all you need to show. That both are smallest fields containing $K$ and $a_0,a_2,...,a_n$. And for the part "How do I see that $K(a_0,a_1,…,a_n)$ is indeed the smallest subfield containing containing $K$ and $a0,a1,…,an$ ?", it was defined so in the book I referred to.

Comment: The smallest field containing $K$ and $a_0$ is $K(a_0)$, right? Then the smallest field containing $K$ and $a_0,a_1$ must contain the field $K(a_0)$ and $a_1$, and thus $K(a_0,a_1)$ (which is defined as the smallest field containing $K$ and $a_0,a_1$) is equal to $K(a_0)(a_1)$. Proceed inductively...